# Optimizing search by user defined data type

Tags: c++

Let's say I have the following code:

```
class ID {
    ID (const std::string& name_, int n_) : name (name_), n(n_) {}
    std::string name;
    int n;
}

T* search_by_ID (const ID& id_);
```

Whenever I want to call `search_by_ID` I need to construct a temporary ID object (if a suitable object isn't already constructed and available), e.g.:

```
ptr=search_by_ID (ID (myname, number));
```

Even if the object is constructed in place, it involves a string copy, which could be slow. So defining a new function (or overloading) seems convenient:

```
T* search_by_ID (const std::string name, int number);
```

Now I can perform a search and no string copies are created. The drawback is that I have to overload `search_by_ID` and code may not be so easy or understand or clear.

Is it possible to have the best of the two approaches? I.e. preventing the first call from creating a copy of the string (myname).

Comment: use `find_if` and pass `name` by reference

Comment: Better do not use all uppercase identifiers except than for preprocessor

Comment: You are right. The real code is slightly different, I just simplified it (actual name is NetID).

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling the function multiple times, and always using the same class, it might be better to change the class a bit, and instead of storing a `std::string` inside, store a **pointer** to a `std::string`. That way you won't have to copy the string all the time while usinge your constructor.

If you're planning on using different classes tho, you may find it better to use **templates**, and make a template out of your function:

```
template <class myType>
T* search(myType &object);
```

You can combine both solutions too of course.

Comment: It's not possible. Sometimes making copies of ID objects is required. Storing a pointer would be a mess.